# Dynamic query retrieval

Tags: php, arrays, notorm

I am using NOTORM to generate queries, and there is one case on the application where the user can select fields, conditions, etc and thus basically come up with custom queries. That way the user can generate a report like 'people with first name = Jack that have spent > 800'.

I am using NOTORM to generate this query, but I'd like to store the query for usage by another part of the application that is not using NOTORM. Is there any function to retrieve the query generated?

This is how the NOTORM object looks after the queries were generated and executed:

```
    object(NotORM_Result)#55 (33) {
  ["single":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["select":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["conditions":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "name = ? "
    [1]=>
    string(12) "surname = ? "
    [2]=>
    string(15) "custom_field_19"
    [3]=>
    string(31) "custom_field_20 BETWEEN ? AND ?"
    [4]=>
    string(21) "custom_field_18 <= ? "
    [5]=>
    string(15) "custom_field_16"
    [6]=>
    string(10) "email = ? "
  }
  ["where":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "name = ? "
    [1]=>
    string(12) "surname = ? "
    [2]=>
    string(52) "custom_field_19 IN ('Yes', 'Sent lender info', 'No')"
    [3]=>
    string(31) "custom_field_20 BETWEEN ? AND ?"
    [4]=>
    string(21) "custom_field_18 <= ? "
    [5]=>
    string(28) "custom_field_16 IN ('Buyer')"
    [6]=>
    string(10) "email = ? "
  }
  ["parameters":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Franco"
    [2]=>
    int(1218146400)
    [3]=>
    int(1249682400)
    [4]=>
    string(3) "800"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "?"
  }
  ["order":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["limit":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["offset":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["group":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["having":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["lock":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["union":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["unionOrder":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["unionLimit":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["unionOffset":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["data":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["referencing":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["aggregation":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["accessed":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["access":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["keys":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["connection":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["driver":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["structure":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["cache":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["notORM":protected]=>
  object(NotORM)#3 (12) {
    ["connection":protected]=>
    object(PDO)#2 (0) {
    }
    ["driver":protected]=>
    string(5) "mysql"
    ["structure":protected]=>
    object(NotORM_Structure_Convention)#4 (4) {
      ["primary":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["foreign":protected]=>
      string(5) "%s_id"
      ["table":protected]=>
      string(2) "%s"
      ["prefix":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["cache":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["notORM":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["table":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["primary":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["rows":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["referenced":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["debug":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["freeze":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["rowClass":protected]=>
    string(10) "NotORM_Row"
  }
  ["table":protected]=>
  string(5) "users"
  ["primary":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["rows":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["referenced":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["debug":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["freeze":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["rowClass":protected]=>
  string(10) "NotORM_Row"
}
```

I could do some kind of script that iterates over 'where' and 'parameters' but seems not too elegant, especially since the order of those arrays is not correct (I would have to do something like replace each "?" with the next item in "parameters")... Any NOTORM functions? Or any more elegant way that you suggest?

This is the 'where' and 'parameters' part in case that you have something elegant for the last option:

```
    ["where":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "name = ? "
    [1]=>
    string(12) "surname = ? "
    [2]=>
    string(52) "custom_field_19 IN ('Yes', 'Sent lender info', 'No')"
    [3]=>
    string(31) "custom_field_20 BETWEEN ? AND ?"
    [4]=>
    string(21) "custom_field_18 <= ? "
    [5]=>
    string(28) "custom_field_16 IN ('Buyer')"
    [6]=>
    string(10) "email = ? "
  }
  ["parameters":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Franco"
    [2]=>
    int(1218146400)
    [3]=>
    int(1249682400)
    [4]=>
    string(3) "800"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "?"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the NotORM_Result object to an string

```php
$sql = (string)$result;
//or
$sql = $result->__toString();
```

Comment: Thanks... But I still see the '?' signs, after converting it I get: SELECT * FROM users WHERE (surname != ? ) AND (custom_field_19 IN ('Yes', 'Sent lender info', 'No')) AND (name = ? )... Why? Where is the full query?